# attempting to make changes to a pod, failing miserably

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, git

This person made changes to a git repository called JSQMessagesViewController.

https://github.com/llz456/JSQMessagesViewController/commit/656b7739076372fae26b4b6a988cc1e87fc1de3e

Before I even made any changes, I tried forking and then pod installed like this:

> pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', :git =>
>   https://github.com/tiago/ThePodProject.git

However when I do that, most of the functions used from that pod no longer work. My guess is I'm missing a submodule or other libraries to download...

how can I make it so that everything that came from the pod is installed ? Is there a more effective way of doing all this??

Comment: Uninstall and then again install pod and ruby. I'm talking about start the whole process all over.

Comment: Try to update the repository using this command pod update POD_NAME